# squid-3.3.8 Compilation Error in IpcIoFile.h File

Tags: c++, squid

I am trying to compile squid squid-3.3.8. 
Facing some errors as below .
How can fix this issue ? Is it related to GCC version ?

```
In file included from Strand.cc:23:0:
../../src/DiskIO/IpcIo/IpcIoFile.h:134:17: error: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
     static std::auto_ptr<Queue> queue; ///< IPC queue
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::auto_ptr` is deprecated since C++11 (as the error says).

Normally that is not reported as an error by the compiler, but as a warning, so the build system is probably using the `-Werror` flag to turn warnings into errors.

You have a few options:

1. Remove the `-Werror` flag.
2. Change the compiler options to explicitly build the code as C++03 rather than a newer standard (`-std=c++03`).
3. Change the source code and replace `std::auto_ptr` with `std::unique_ptr` (be sure you know *exactely* how they differ when modifying the code).